# Word for data-series comprised from resampled, interpolated and merged data-series

Tags: time-series, definition, interpolation

Two series of data-points for a specific curve are given:

1. $x$ as a function of $y$ (high resolution, low range)
2. $y$ as a function of $x$  (low resolution, high range)

The two series are merged and used to build a model. Data is sampled from the model and a new resulting data-series is produced.

**What do you call the resulting series?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've decided to describe the process and use *"resulting series"*